# Display Error Message for Custom Validation in Laravel 4

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I have created a custom error function by creating a class;

```
<?php

class CoreValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{
    public function validatePostcode($attribute, $value, $parameters = null)
    {
        $regex = "/^((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY])))) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$/i";
        if(preg_match($regex ,$value)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I reference it in my model;

```
public static $rules = array(
        'first_name' => 'required|Max:45',
        'surname' => 'required|Max:45',
        'address_line_1' => 'required|Max:255',
        'address_line_2' => 'Max:255',
        'address_line_3' => 'Max:255',
        'town' => 'required|Max:45',
        'county' => 'Max:45',
        'postcode' => 'required|Postcode',
        'phone_number' => 'required|Max:22'
    );
```

It has been registered in my **global.php**;

```
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
        return new CoreValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
    });
```

It all works well, but the error message it returns is

> validation.postcode

How/where do I set a custom error message for this?
I have tried setting **app/lang/en/validation.php** with (neither work);

```
'custom' => array(
        "validation.postcode" => "my error message 1",
        "postcode" => "my error message 2"
    )
```

P.S. I know that there is a regex validation method already, but this problem is more generic for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify the default error message when extending the Validation class in Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647044/how-to-specify-the-default-error-message-when-extending-the-validation-class-in)

Comment: @AbishekRSrikaanth that answer is for custom placeholders in error messages, not the actual message of a custom method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I have cracked it.

I added the message to the main array in **app/lang/en/validation.php**, not into the custom sub-array.

```
return array(
    ...
    "url" => "The :attribute format is invalid.",
    "postcode" => "my error message 2",
    ...
)
```

If this isn't the correct way, then someone is free to correct me.

Comment: I did it the same way and think also this is the correct way.

Comment: I'd very much like to know if that's correct also, it seems sketchy.

Comment: @uɐɥʇɐᴎ I just had this same issue - see my posted answer on how to correctly utilize the custom validation array.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me with a 3rd party custom rule :-( https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator

Comment: File is in a slightly different place in v5: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/lang/en/validation.php#L15

Comment: In laravel 5.1 this file located at *`resources/lang/en/validation.php`*

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setCustomMessages()` method to assign custom messages like the bellow code

```
<?php

class CoreValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{

    private $custom_messages = array(
        "customvalidation" => "my error message.",
    );

    public function __construct($translator, $data, $rules, $messages = array(), $customAttributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
        $this->setCustomMessages($this->custom_messages);
    }

    public function validateCustomvalidation($attribute, $value, $parameters = null)
    {
        // validation code here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe this code more better :

```
// for example I am using sub-array custom at default validation file, but you can do it in other file as you wishes.
..other..
'custom' => array(
        'email' => array(
            'required' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
        ),
        "required"         => "Hey!!! don't forget at :attribute field is required.",
    ),
..other..

// you can determine your custom languages at your wishes file
$messages = \Lang::get('validation.custom');

Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

Comment: if you are doing package development, this is the only good option.  \Lang::get('package::validation.custom');

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules):

> In some cases, you may wish to specify your custom messages in a language file instead of passing them directly to the Validator. To do so, add your messages to custom array in the app/lang/xx/validation.php language file.

```
'custom' => array(
    'email' => array(
        'required' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
    ),
),
```

That means, in your case,

```
'custom' => array(
    'postcode' => array(
        'PostCode' => 'error message for PostCode rule',
        'required' => 'error message for required rule',
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to utilize the custom validation messages array in app/lang/xx/validation.php, the correct way is as follows:

```
'custom' => array(
    'formFieldName' => array(
        'postcode' => 'error message for PostCode rule',
        'iamalwayslowercase' => 'error message for this rule'
    ),
),
```

Note that you use the name of the form field and then in the array you use the lowercased name of the rule.

Comment: If you wanted to keep your $messages with the $rules, you could also just have the following in your model (so you don't mess with the language files): `public static $messages = array ( 'formFieldName.postcode' => 'error message for PostCode rule' );`

Comment: This still doesn't work for me with a 3rd party custom rule :-( https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator

Comment: @groovenectar I am unable to review your code, but I can definitely say the above works and have been using it for some time.

Answer (score 0):

The code below also works perfectly, take note of the underscore on the index of the `$customValidatorMessages` array. Hope it helps someone :-)

```
class CoreValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{
    /**
     * The array of custom validator error messages.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $customValidatorMessages = array(); 

    public function validatePostcode($attribute, $value, $parameters = null)
    {
        $regex = "/^((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY])))) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$/i";
        if(preg_match($regex ,$value)) {
            return true;
        }

        $this->customValidatorMessages['post_code'] = 'Postcode error message.';

        $this->setCustomMessages($this->customValidatorMessages);

        return false;
    }
}
```