# How to do laravel validation error showing with anchor tags

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

When validation doesn't pass, it goes back to the page with the form, displaying all errors. In my case, that's a very long page, with the form and errors at the very bottom. ***How do I let it go back to that page, but with an anchor tag?*** So the user wouldn't have to scroll down again to see the form and the errors.

I have this code in my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{        

    // Validate request...
    $this->validate($request, [
        'content' => 'required',
    ]);

    // Store new post..
```

And this in my view:

```
// Show errors if there are any
@if (isset($errors))
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <em><p class="text-danger">{{ $error }}</p></em>
    @endforeach
@endif
   // Form goes here...
```

---

Definitly not a duplicate of [Display Error Message For Custom Validation In Laravel-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250917/display-error-message-for-custom-validation-in-laravel-4). In that question anchor tags aren't even mentioned, the most important part of this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display Error Message for Custom Validation in Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250917/display-error-message-for-custom-validation-in-laravel-4)

Comment: Definitly not a duplicate, anchor tags aren't even mentioned in that "possible duplicate you posted"

Comment: create a custom error message using  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250917/display-error-message-for-custom-validation-in-laravel-4) this link link <a href="#email_error" .......

Answer (score 2):

It looks kind of strange but it works for Laravel 8.27.0

I guess it will work for the older versions as well.

Create a regular anchor and set it in your form:

```
<a id="yourform"></a>
<form action="url-where-you-process-the-form#yourform" method="post">
...
</form>
```

NOTE: There's no need for `url-where-you-process-the-form` to match the URL of your current page.