# Laravel Validation custom message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am facing a problem with laravel custom validation message, here is what I have:

```
$rules = [
    'first_name'            => 'required|alpha|min:2',
    'last_name'             => 'required|alpha|min:2',
    'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . Input::get('id') . ',id',
    'password'              => 'alpha_num|between:6,12|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'alpha_num|between:6,12',
    'address'               => 'regex:/^[a-z0-9- ]+$/i|min:2',
    'city'                  => 'alpha|min:2',
    'state'                 => 'alpha|min:2|max:2',
    'zip'                   => 'numeric|min:5|max:5',
    'phone'                 => 'regex:/^\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}$/',
];
$messages = [
    'unique' => 'The :attribute already been registered.',
    'regex'  => 'The :attribute number has to be formated : xxx-xxx-xxxx.',
];
```

Now if there is a problem with the address or the phone number since both have regex validation rule , the error message will be : The :attribute number has to be formated : xxx-xxx-xxxx, How could I have custom message for each different one ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify the default error message when extending the Validation class in Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647044/how-to-specify-the-default-error-message-when-extending-the-validation-class-in)

Comment: actually I just solved it now , :) all you need is this

Comment: If you solved this, please answer your question to benefit future SO users.

Comment: $messages = array(
'unique' => 'The :attribute already been registered.','phone.regex' => 'The :attribute number is invalid , accepted format: xxx-xxx-xxxx','address.regex' => 'The :attribute format is invalid.',);

Comment: 'fieldname.unique' or 'fieldname.regex'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the way to do it , just instead of using 'regex' , use 'phone.regex'

```
$rules = [
    'first_name'            => 'required|alpha|min:2',
    'last_name'             => 'required|alpha|min:2',
    'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . Input::get('id') . ',id',
    'password'              => 'alpha_num|between:6,12|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'alpha_num|between:6,12',
    'address'               => 'regex:/^[a-z0-9- ]+$/i|min:2',
    'city'                  => 'alpha|min:2',
    'state'                 => 'alpha|min:2|max:2',
    'zip'                   => 'numeric|min:5|max:5',
    'phone'                 => 'regex:/^\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}$/',
];
$messages = [
    'unique'        => 'The :attribute already been registered.',
    'phone.regex'   => 'The :attribute number is invalid , accepted format: xxx-xxx-xxxx',
    'address.regex' => 'The :attribute format is invalid.',
];
```

Comment: didn't know it until today :) i have also removed an extra array closing-a syntax error :)