# Add a custom validation error message laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I can do something like this to validate something on the controller.

```
$this->validate($request,[
'myinput'=>'regex:some pattern'
]);
```

and the output of this would be something like this

> The myinput format is invalid.

What i want was to show something of my own message

> Only some pattern allowed

How do i achieve this on laravel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Validation custom message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117999/laravel-validation-custom-message)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add custom validation messages to language files, like `resources/lang/en/validation.php`.

Another way to do that, from docs:

```
'custom' => [
    'email' => [
        'regex' => 'Please use your company email address to register. Webmail services are not permitted.'
    ],
    'lawyer_legal_fields' => [
        'number_of_areas' => 'You\'re not allowed to select so many practice areas'
    ],
],
```

> You may customize the error messages used by the form request by overriding the messages method.

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'title.required' => 'A title is required',
        'body.required'  => 'A message is required',
    ];
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

Comment: @BOTJr. I guess a better way is to add custom messages into language the files.

Answer (score 9):

There are many techniques to customize validator messages.

#### Validate inside the controller

It would be looked like this

```
$validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name'=>'required|max:120',
    'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
    'password'=>'nullable|min:6|confirmed'
], 
[
    'name.required' => 'User name must not be empty!',
    'name.max' => 'The maximun length of The User name must not exceed :max',
    'name.regex' => 'Use name can not contain space',
    'email.required' => 'Email must not be empty!',
    'email.email' => 'Incorrect email address!',
    'email.unique' => 'The email has already been used',
    'password.min' => 'Password must contain at least 6 characters',
    'password.confirmed' => 'Failed to confirm password'
]);
```

The first param is inputs to validate

The second array is validator rules

The last params is the customized validator messages

In which, the synctax is *[input_variable_name].[validator_name] => "Customized message"*

#### Second apprach: using InfyOm Laravel Generator

I like this approach the most. It provides useful tools for generating such as *Controller, Models, Views, API etc*.
And yet, create and update `Request` file. in which the Request file is using `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` where this class is extended from `Illuminate\Http\Request`.
It is mean that we can access *Request* in this file and perform validating for the incoming requests.
Here is the most interesting part to me.
The generated request file contains *rules* function, for example like this

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique:flights,name|max:20',
        'airline_id' => 'nullable|numeric|digits_between:1,10',
    ];
}
```

This function actually returns the validator-rules and validate them against the inputs.
And you can override function *messages* from *Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest* to customize the error message as you need:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'required' => "This field is required",
        \\... etc
    ];
}
```

Nonetheless, you can do many nore with the generated request files, just refer to file in vendor folder `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http` from your project.
Here is the Infyom github link [InfyOmLabs - laravel-generator](https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator)