# Laravel nova gt and lt validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Gt and lt validations are working on laravel nova, it gives me error message "validation.lt.numeric" . i want to customize it like "user limit can not greater than global limit". Can anyone tell this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Validation custom message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117999/laravel-validation-custom-message)

Comment: No. i have two fields 1. global limit, 2. user limit. ... user limit can not greater than global limit.. i want this validation error message in laravel nova

Comment: Can you share your code with us? What did you do so far?

Comment: @gguney i have resolved this....I just add custom message in validation.php file of laravel nova

Comment: maybe you can post your own anser to help other getting to the site

Comment: GT, GTE, LT and LTE are laravel validations, just write them in laravel nova resource field rule and add custom message in validation.php.